# Using Postman variables across tabs

Tags: postman

Postman has been an amazing tool for me, but I have some questions about using variables.  In my collection I have 4 tabs/requests.

The first is to get a token that is used in the other three (the token expires after 15 minutes so I have to rerun that request frequently and update the other 3).  It needs to be passed in the headers of the other three requests.  I'm familiar with the {{variable}} syntax, but I'm not sure how to dynamically set the variable after running the first request.

The second is similar, where I'd like to be able to set a string manually in some central location and use it in all of the requests.  For instance, the URL is https://the.api.com/v1/{{someidvalue}}/abc so where can I change that in a single location manually to be reused across the collection?

Thank you!

Comment: Setting those variables in a single place at either the environment or global level would sort your second question. Not sure what you mean for the first, it will set a new value dynamically each time you make the first request and set the value.

Comment: I'm hoping to run the first, get the token value from the JSON response, and use that value for requests 2-4 without updating the headers value manually.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

To change the value based on server response you can use the test feature [Postman test script](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/test_scripts)

For exemple

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Authorization","Bearer " + jsonData.result.accessToken);
```

The central location that you are looking for is the enviroment [postman manage environments](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments)

Comment: If you use an environment variable, remember to define your environment variable in the environment you are using to run the collection. I was recently having trouble because I kept trying to run them in "no environment" and it would not set or retrieve the batch_id variable I had defined because I had defined it as an environment variable.